# Create path from path value?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Can i create a Path using its value??

```
 Path p=new Path();
 p.getElements().add(new MoveTo(mouse.getX(), mouse.getY()));
 System.out.Print(p);
```

This will print

> Path@29f12030

can i convert this into path again?

Answer (score 1):

You have already created a path and it's still a path, you don't need to convert it.

When you call `System.out.print(p)` you invoke the default `toString` function on your `p` object, which prints an internal Java reference to your Path (e.g. `Path@29f12030`).
If you override the default `toString` method with your own implementation, as is shown in the sample below, your print statement will display the value of the path.

```
public class PrintPath extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Path p = new PrintedPath();
    p.getElements().add(new MoveTo(100, 150));
    System.out.println(p);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane()));
    stage.show();
  } 

  class PrintedPath extends Path {
    @Override public String toString() {
      StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
      for (PathElement e: getElements()) {
        if (e instanceof MoveTo) {
          MoveTo m = (MoveTo) e;
          b.append("M").append(m.getX()).append(" ").append(m.getY()).append(" ");
        }
        // logic to display other path element types could be added here . . .
      }
      return "Path{ " + b.toString() + "}";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to know whether building path from a value is possible..then We Can send data over network in a non clumsy way

Comment: As an easily serialized (to string) and deserialized path format, I'd suggest using an [SVGPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/shape/SVGPath.html).  If you do this, see the [SVG string path format specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should elaborate your purpose of sending data over network in a context of your app architecture. Give some fundamental details about it. In my understanding, you want to send a `Path` instance over the network and able to process it on the other end. If so,
- have a look to a [serialization API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/). Read the post about it ["How to transfer objects over network using java"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3124702/682495). Extend the `Path` or wrap it into another class then implement Serializable.
 - Or, refer to [Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)](http://jaxb.java.net/). Basically by using it you can convert/marshal the objects to XML strings and transfer over the network and then unmarshal it. Here is [hello world example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/).
 - Or, implement your own encoding/decoding mechanism to transfer the `Path` object.

Comment: What i'm trying to do update path using database... So the two users can work on same drawin.. In short collaborative drawing...

i first considered doing it by sending x and y positions along with path stroke n stuff.. but its too clumsy.. So i thought sending path values should be helpful