# Static ArrayList does not modify in another class

Tags: java

I am working on a client - server application and I have the following problem.

In one class (Server), I have a static reference to an ArrayList called clients and a static getter getClientsArray(). In another class (ServerThread), I use the same ArrayList and I successfully modify it (add / delete clients).

For every client, I call the method getClientsArray() and get that ArrayList. The problem is that the ArrayList is empty here, in Client class. I check it every time I update it in ServerThread (after a client connects) and it should have something in it.

```
    public class Server {
            private static ArrayList<User> clients = new ArrayList<User>();

            public static ArrayList<User> getClientsArray() {
                  return clients;
            }

            and somewhere I call: new ServerThread(sock, users).start();
    }

    public class ServerThread extends Thread {
        private ArrayList<User> users;

        public ServerThread(Socket client, ArrayList<User> users) {
                this.client = client;
                this.users = users;
        }
        if I modify users in this class, the changes will occur
    }

    public class Client extends JFrame {
        private ArrayList<User> users;
            public Client() {
                initGraphics();

                users = Server.getClientsArray();
                System.out.println(users.size()); <- This line always writes 0!!    
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You probably need to add the proper synchronization around all access to the ArrayList. Post your code so folks can see it.

Comment: The moment you use the phrases "Client" and "Static data" together, you have invoked the possible wrath of the gods of concurrency.

Comment: And do you at some place add elements to `Server.clients`? So far, the size being always 0 is entirely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static variables are only global to one program instance.  Here, you have at least two programs running; You have one server program, and at least one other client program.  The clients and server do not share any common heap, or program variables, so the static list will only be seen by that program.

If you want to share the list, you will need to pass it through sockets or some other data transfer.  This question, [How to transfer objects over network using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124702/how-to-transfer-objects-over-network-using-java), has a code example of how to pass objects through sockets.

Comment: Is there any possibility to send the reference to the list to every client, so when the list changes in the Server class, connected clients' list will also be updated?

Comment: You are going to run into the same issue as a reference refers to a memory location that only is accessible/makes sense to one program.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple rule defined by Brian Goetz in [JCIP](http://jcip.net/):

> If multiple threads access the same mutable state variable without appropriate synchronization, *your program is broken*.

You have `clients` mutable state and you don't use any mean of synchronizing access to it.

Comment: How could I synchronize clients variable? If I did it, would it be visible in every Client class instance, or only in Server and ServerThread?